# Summing quantities that are grouped by more than one field

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sum

This is a follow on from my previous questions. I just feel that its easier if I explain it all again as I want to try to get more detail out of my query. So here we go:

Sample Table:
(note: the table has 100's of ID's each with numerous different LOTNO's)

ITEMNO   LOTNO   TRANS_QUAN   TRANS_TYPE

---

```
 1      45        16          PO  
 1       3         2          PO  
 1      45        47          MH  
 1      45         3          MH
 1       3         8          MH
```

What I have so far does not take into account the different LotNo's for each ID, rather it sums based on ID and TYPE. The code below sums all Quantity values for TYPE = 'PO' with ID = 1. and then compares them with all summed quantity values for TYPE = 'MANUAL/BACKFLUSH' with ID = 1. This code works perfectly in this regard (big thanks to Nicholas Krasnov with this one):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT TR.ITEMNO
         , ROUND(SUM(TR.TRANS_QUAN * (DECODE(TR.TRANS_TYPE, 'PO', 1, 0)))) AS SUM_IN
         , ROUND(SUM(TR.TRANS_QUAN * (DECODE(TR.TRANS_TYPE, 'MANUAL/BACKFLUSH', 1,0))))AS SUM_OUT
     FROM IQMS.TRANSLOG TR
     GROUP BY IQMS.TR.ITEMNO
     ORDER BY IQMS.TR.ITEMNO)
 WHERE SUM_OUT > SUM_IN
```

I want to break the sum calculation down further and incorporate the LOTNO field. So in the table above, for ID = 1, I want to sum all values for ID = 1, LotNo = 45 and TYPE = PO and then compare them to ID = 1, LotNo = 45 and TYPE = 'MANUAL\BACKFLUSH'.

I then want to move on to compare(ID = 1, LOTNO = 3, TYPE = 'PO') with (ID = 1, LOTNO = 3, TYPE ='MANUAL/BACKFLUSH') and so on.

I also only want to return records in which SUM_OUT > SUM_IN

I would hope for my output to be something like

```
ID      LOTNO     SUM_IN      SUM_OUT    

 1        45        30           50
 1         3         2            8
```

Any ideas on how i can incorporate this, to give a more specific result set?? Probably something simple like an extra GROUP BY or something?? I hope I have been clear on what I hope to achieve.

Thanks for the continued support guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query does what you want . . .

```
select id, lotno,
       sum(case when type = 'PO' then quantity else 0 end) as sum_in,
       sum(case when type = 'MANUAL/BACKFLUSH' then quantity else 0 end) as sum_out
from IQMS.TRANSLOG TR
group by id, lotno
```

The `case` statement is standard SQL; `decode` is specific to Oracle.  Also, I wasn't sure which column names to use, since they are inconsistent between your question and the code sample.  I used the shortest form.

To return records where `sum_out > sum_in`, you can embed this as a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select id, lotno,
             sum(case when type = 'PO' then quantity else 0
                 end) as sum_in,
             sum(case when type = 'MANUAL/BACKFLUSH' then quantity else 0
                 end) as sum_out
      from IQMS.TRANSLOG TR
      group by id, lotno
     ) t
where sum_out > sum_in
```

You can also do this with a `having` clause.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I have made some edits to make what i want clearer. I only want to return records where SUM_OUT>SUM_IN.

Answer (score 1):

According to your sample data, is that what you are looking for?

```
select *
  from ( SELECT TR.ITEMNO
              , tr.lotno
              , ROUND(SUM(TR.TRANS_QUAN * (DECODE(TR.TRANS_TYPE, 'PO', 1, 0)))) AS SUM_IN
              , ROUND(SUM(TR.TRANS_QUAN * (DECODE(TR.TRANS_TYPE, 'MH', 1,0))))AS SUM_OUT
          FROM TRANSLOG TR
         GROUP BY TR.ITEMNO, tr.lotno
         ORDER BY TR.ITEMNO
       )
 where sum_out > sum_in
```

Comment: Thanks mate, just figured it out. Switched my code from decode to case. see below!! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!! :) :)

```
SELECT *
FROM

  (SELECT TR.ITEMNO, TR.LOTNO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TR.TRANS_TYPE = 'PO' THEN TR.TRANS_QUAN ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_IN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TR.TRANS_TYPE = 'MANUAL/BACKFLUSH' THEN TR.TRANS_QUAN ELSE 0 END)AS SUM_OUT
   FROM IQMS.TRANSLOG TR
   GROUP BY TR.ITEMNO, TR.LOTNO
   ORDER BY TR.ITEMNO, TR.LOTNO)

WHERE SUM_OUT > SUM_IN
AND SUM_IN != '0'
```

Thanks you guys for all the help!!